# jquery tmpl sum result why quadruple

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

```
var cnt = [{cnt: [1, 2, 3]}]
```

my template

```
<script id="myTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
{%= ($data.cntTot = 0, '') %}
{%each(index, item) cnt%}
    cnt: {%= ($data.cntTot += item, item) %}<br>
{%/each%}
TOT: {%= cntTot %}
```

code

```
$('#myTmpl').tmpl(cnt).appendTo($('body'));
```

result

> cnt: 1 cnt: 2 cnt: 3 TOT: 24

sum result why quadruple ??

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{$= $data.cntTot %}`?

Comment: TempValue cntTot created in the Tmpl

Comment: The template created `$data.cntTot`, not `cntTot`.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation of the template plugin you're using? I tried the link in the tag wiki, but it doesn't look anything like this.

Comment: https://github.com/KanbanSolutions/jquery-tmpl

Comment: I don't see anything there that suggests that you can assign to `$data.xxx` and then print it as just `xxx` without `$data.` before it.

Comment: now using template plugin link

Answer (score 0):

update code (tmpl)

```
   <script id="myTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
   {%= ($data.cntTot = 0, '') %}
   {%each(index, item) cnt%}
       {%= ($data.cntVar = (cntTot + item), '') %}
       cnt: {%= ($data.cntTot = cntVar, item) %}<br>
   {%/each%}
   TOT: {%= cntTot %}
   </script>
```

RESULT

```
cnt: 1
cnt: 2
cnt: 3
TOT: 6
```

Comment: But I do not know why